# Smooth transition in Framer Motion Scroll

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, scroll, framer-motion

I'm just learning to use Framer Motion and I just can't get the hang of this. I want text moving from one end to another (just like a marquee), but with increasing speed on scroll. Here's how it is supposed to work: https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-scroll-velocity-forked-pf7q7l?file=/src/App.tsx:0-2323

But the thing works fine, the problem is that the transition from one end to the other isn't smooth.
Here's my code:

```
function ParallaxText({ children, baseVelocity = 100 }) {
  const baseX = useMotionValue(0);
  const { scrollY } = useScroll();
  const scrollVelocity = useVelocity(scrollY);
  const smoothVelocity = useSpring(scrollVelocity, {
    damping: 50,
    stiffness: 400,
  });
  const velocityFactor = useTransform(smoothVelocity, [0, 1000], [0, 5], {
    clamp: false,
  });

  /**
   * This is a magic wrapping for the length of the text - you
   * have to replace for wrapping that works for you or dynamically
   * calculate
   */
  const x = useTransform(baseX, (v) => `${wrap(-20, -45, v)}%`);

  const directionFactor = useRef(1);
  useAnimationFrame((t, delta) => {
    let moveBy = directionFactor.current * baseVelocity * (delta / 1000);

    /**
     * This is what changes the direction of the scroll once we
     * switch scrolling directions.
     */
    if (velocityFactor.get() < 0) {
      directionFactor.current = -1;
    } else if (velocityFactor.get() > 0) {
      directionFactor.current = 1;
    }

    moveBy += directionFactor.current * moveBy * velocityFactor.get();

    baseX.set(baseX.get() + moveBy);
  });

  /**
   * The number of times to repeat the child text should be dynamically calculated
   * based on the size of the text and viewport. Likewise, the x motion value is
   * currently wrapped between -20 and -45% - this 25% is derived from the fact
   * we have four children (100% / 4). This would also want deriving from the
   * dynamically generated number of children.
   */
  return (
    <div className="parallax">
      <motion.div className="scroller" style={{ x }}>
        <span>{children} </span>
        <span>{children} </span>
        <span>{children} </span>
        <span>{children} </span>
      </motion.div>
    </div>
  );
}

const PageSec2 = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <section>
        <ParallaxText baseVelocity={-5}>Framer Motion</ParallaxText>
        <ParallaxText baseVelocity={5}>Scroll velocity</ParallaxText>
      </section>
    </>
  );
};
```

CSS:

```
.progress {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 5px;
  background: var(--accent);
  bottom: 100px;
}

.parallax {
  overflow: hidden;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  line-height: 0.8;
  margin: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.parallax .scroller {
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 64px;
  display: flex;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.parallax span {
  display: block;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

It would be really helpful to get this solved, thanks in advance!